Looking for name of 10-pin IC with code At7HA from Samsung NVME PM981
I'm new to this forum and english is not my native language so please don't be mad :)
I'm trying to repair my Samsung PM981 Nvme 256GB SSD. The At7HA IC broke so i want to buy replacement but i can't find any name for it on the web. Tried contacting samsung but they didn't answer. Can anyone help me find any data about this piece?


Likely made by Silergy. If you google search for Silergy "Atxyz" you'll find a two posts about this IC but no datasheet. Most Silergy datasheets are not publicly available, so it's unlikely that you will find out the exact model.
